# APEX ORDS Rest API returns content-type:text/html

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, oracle-apex

We have installed Oracle APEX on our application server with ORDS and Weblogic app server. We are trying to use it to create simple ReST APIs that would fetch data from our database (11gR2). I have an HTML page developed which uses `jqgrid` to convert the `json` data from the ReST API to Tabular grid. The `GET` request by `jqgrid` to the URI is met with a `404 Resource not found` error.

The `jqgrid` codes looks like this-

```
 $("#jqGrid").jqGrid({
                url: 'http://nsrmss01:9002/ords/oracle_retail_rest/comm/js',
                mtype: 'GET',
                datatype: 'json'
                styleUI : 'Bootstrap',                
                colModel: [
                    { label: 'Database', name: 'DBNAME', width: 100,editable: true },
                    { label: 'SID', name: 'DBSID', width: 100,editable: true },
                    { label: 'Port', name: 'DBPORT', width: 100,editable: true },
                    { label: 'Last Refreshed', name: 'LASTREFRESHED', width: 150,editable: true ,
                            edittype : 'text',
                            editoptions: {
                            // dataInit is the client-side event that fires upon initializing the toolbar search field for a column
                            // use it to place a third party control to customize the toolbar
                            dataInit: function (element) {
                               $(element).datepicker({
                                                        autoclose: true,
                                                        format: 'dd-M-yyyy',
                                                        orientation : 'bottom'
                                });
                            }
                        }
                      },
                    { label: 'Server Status', name: 'STATUS', width: 150,editable: true ,
                              edittype: "select",
                              editoptions: {
                                    value:"AVAILABLE:Available;UNREACH:Unreachable;DOWN:Down"}
                    }
                ],
                        viewrecords: true,
                height: 250,
                loadonce: true,
                rowNum: 20,
                pager: "#jqGridPager"
            });
```

The webpage has a simple `jqgrid` table which should load the `json` content which looks like below (3 rows for root `dbdata` on the `json` array)-

```
{
   "dbdata":    [
            {
         "dbname": "servdbp01",
         "dbsid": "PROD",
         "dbport": 1621,
         "status": "AVAILABLE"
      },
            {
         "dbname": "servdbd06",
         "dbsid": "DEV01",
         "dbport": 1621,
         "lastrefreshed": "2015-01-01T08:00:00Z",
         "status": "AVAILABLE"
      },
            {
         "dbname": "servdbd06",
         "dbsid": "SUP01",
         "dbport": 1621,
         "lastrefreshed": "2015-02-15T08:00:00Z",
         "status": "AVAILABLE"
      }
   ]
}
```

I have also tried `jsonReader : {root: "dbdata"}` as option in the `jqgrid`.

Browser debug shows this-

[image]

I am noticing that the `content-type` in the response header sent by the service is `text/html` as you can see below-

[image]

Should the `content-type` be `application/json`? and is that the issue? If so how do I change/configure ORDS to set the content-type? I am creating the ReST API using the APEX UI and have tested the API to be working through APEX test and SoapUI. I have looked here and else where about this issue but can't find anything relevant, so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Note: If I use `datatype:'jsonstring'` then the error goes away, but then I am not sure how to convert the response back to a string. If I use `$.getJSON()` to get the `JSON` data i am getting a proper response back (see screenshot and code below). But I am just not sure how to use it in the JQGrid.

```
$.getJSON('http://nsrmss01:9002/ords/oracle_retail_rest/comm/js', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
         });
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason of the error 404 Resource not found could be the parameters, which will be sent to the server. You should add jqGrid option `prmNames` to suppress sending of `_search`, `nd` and other:

```
prmNames: { nd: null, search: null, sort: null, order: null, rows: null, page: null }
```

Then you should fix the values of `name` properties used in `colModel`. JavaScript is case sensitive and you have to use, for example, `name: 'dbname'` instead of `name: 'DBNAME'`.

Finally I'd recommend you to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) instead of commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you currently used. Free jqGrid can be used under MIT or GPL v2 license completely free of charge. You need just change `styleUI : 'Bootstrap'` parameter to `guiStyle: "bootstrap"`. See [the article](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#bootstrap) for more details. Other optimizations can be done after your code will work.

Comment: Excellent! thanks so much. and thanks for the note on the free option. Although 1 thing to note, I created another web service using Nodejs and the data was exactly the same. In chrome inspector, it showed it was sending the `prmNames` but it was still able to get the data and populate the grid without any issues, but for this API it would say 404. I still don't understand how this won't work with the params and the other API would. Thanks though it solves my problem.

Comment: By the way, I also had to add `jsonReader: {root: "dbdata"}` to make it work.

Comment: i had to let you know how much I appreciate all your answers in SO. I learned a lot about jqgrid. I feel that all your answers here are superb and spot on and solves almost every issue and these need to be collected somehow. I know you manage the free-jqgrid code in multiple CDNs but have you thought about trying out SO Documentation to make a collection of all your content here and then link back to the github wiki. I am no expert in js but let me know if I can help.

Comment: @Annjawn: Thank you! Creating of full documentation is really **complex**. I included in the last version (4.14.0) the file [free-jqgrid.d.ts](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/ts/free-jqgrid.d.ts), which describes the options, callbacks and events of free jqGrid for the usage in TypeScript. Such file is created manually. One can see that it has more as 2000 lines. The descriptions of all the information, creating the demos and so on will be really long besause the introduction part could be really long.

Comment: @Annjawn: See [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/jqPivot-in-version-4.9) an example the description (not full of `jqPivot` method only. I started with documenting of free jqGrid in [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) and created the first pages of documentation and demos [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) and [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/examples/index.html). I develop free jqGrid in my free time and provide it completely free of charge. I have to do my main job, which get me money too. The lack of time is my main problem.